# Solve $\sqrt{a^2z^2-b^2}=-\sqrt{a^2 \tilde{z}^2-b^2}$ over $\mathbb{C}$.

Tags: complex-numbers

I wish to solve the following algebraic equation
$$\sqrt{a^2z^2-b^2}=-\sqrt{a^2 \tilde{z}^2-b^2}$$
over $\mathbb{C}$.

Note that $\tilde{z}$ does not represent a complex conjugate. Instead, I wish to parametrize $\tilde{z}$ as a function of $z$. I worry that I am making a mistake because of sloppiness in my notation or general reasoning, so despite the embarrassing simplicity of the problem, I decided to post it here.

$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{a^2z^2-b^2} &=e^{\pi i}\sqrt{a^2 \tilde{z}^2-b^2} \\
a^2z^2-b^2 &=e^{2\pi i}\left(a^2 \tilde{z}^2-b^2\right) \\
a^2z^2 + \left(e^{2\pi i} - 1\right) b^2 &= a^2 e^{2\pi i} \tilde{z}^2 \\
z^2 e^{-2\pi i} + a^{-2} \left(1 - e^{-2\pi i}\right) b^2 &= \tilde{z}^2 \\
\sqrt{z^2 e^{-2\pi i} + a^{-2} \left(1 - e^{-2\pi i}\right) b^2} &= \tilde{z} \\
\end{align}
$$

In a magical world, I would be tempted to equate $1$ and $e^{-2 \pi i}$; however, that would lose a factor of $e^{-2 \pi i}$ in front of $b^2$. Is there any way to clean up my answer? Does anybody happen to have a means of animating branch cuts using computer software?

Comment: You should specify what $\sqrt{\cdot}$ stands for here (principal value, maybe?), and use a different variable name e.g. $w$ rather than $\bar z$ to avoid confusion. To the question, $(-1)^2 = 1$ and you don't even need to write it as $-1 = e^{\pi i}$ for that. Also, $e^{2\pi i}=1$ and there is no point in carrying it along. What you have to do is solve the resulting equation $a^2z^2 = a^2 w^2$ for $w$, then verify whether/which solutions satisfy the original equation. The latter is necessary because squaring an equation is a non-reversible step.

Comment: @dxiv, thank you. Would not $w=\pm z$ be the only two solutions of $a^2 z^2 = a^2 w^2$? $w=z$ is a solution if and only if $z = \pm \frac{b}{a}$ as both sides will then be $0$. The introduction of a minus sign in the case of $w=-z$ is lost during squaring, because it is, as you said, an irreversible process -- hence, my confusion.

Comment: That is essentially correct. If $a = 0$ then any $w$ is a solution, regardless of $z$. Otherwise if $a \ne 0$ the equation has solutions iff $z = \pm \frac{b}{a}$, and in that case the solutions are $w = \pm z$. That's assuming $\sqrt{\cdot}$ denotes the principal square root.

Comment: @dxiv If we instead use $\sqrt{\cdot}$ do denote a multivalued function, are there more solutions available? I would think that everything would differ by a phase of $2n\pi$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, rendering all other solutions the same for most purposes. I guess that I had just assumed that this equation had more than a nontrivial result, which lead me to write my clumsy argument mentioned in the question.

Comment: If you take $\sqrt{\cdot}$ as the multivalued function, then for $a \ne 0$ the solutions would be $w = \pm z$ for all $z$. But, in that case, it would be redundant (and, in fact, quite odd) to write the original equation with a minus sign on the RHS, since $\sqrt{\cdot} = -\sqrt{\cdot}$ as multivalued functions.